# How to implement dynamic dropdown on rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Followings are my models

```
class Country
  has_many: cities
end

class City
  belongs_to :country
end

class Airport
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :country
  # I really need to have both city_id and country_id on airport
end
```

I am using Rails Admin. When I go to add or edit an `Airport` I want to be able to dynamically generate `city` dropdown based of the selected `country`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Rails Admin doesn't support it. You need to do it by yourself with your own script. [Reference](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1654).

But fortunately, there is always a good guy in the world. Here is some reference you can learn. http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised

Answer (score 0):

```
class Airport
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :country

  #customization of rails admin
  RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.model 'Airport' do
      edit do
        field :country_id, :enum do
          enum do
            Country.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
          end
        end
        field :city_id, :enum do
          enum do
            City.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can do something like this, this will show all country and all city in dropdown list, and you can write custom js that you are asking.

Comment: for more details you can follow this `https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields`
I hope it helped! Please feel free to upvote/accept if you like